# buildroot X server set RGB value

Tags: linux, x11, xserver, buildroot, uclinux

I would set RGB color on my screen using X server.
I already installed on my arm board buildroot with X server and all X11r7 application.
I would set color by code rgb ( example #FFe3a1 or color name), I tried by rgb.txt file but I cant found rgb application.

Anyone can help me suggesting some X application or sample sample code using X Server.

Answer (score 2):

Use xsetroot:

```
xsetroot -solid '#f73f6b'
```

will make your background a nice shade of pink. The color is specified with a hexadecimal color code, just like HTML. The quotes (') around the colorcode are just there to prevent the shell from interpreting the '#' character as the start of a comment.

Note that most compositing window managers will hide your true root window so it won't work there.

Comment: already done, but not wworkingI dont understand why, sorry after xsetroot command run I can see change color or it is necessary a reboot?

Comment: No reboot necessary; that would actually reset the background. I suspect in your case your window manager is hiding the real root window. I don't know yet of a way to obtain your virtual root window. It must be possible since desktop pictures are common, so a solid color must be too.

Comment: Anyway I note that change only desktop color, if I run for example a browser chrome, I see the same white before, I would modify RGB value for all item on monitor

Comment: I would cchange the color temperature, I try by xgamma application, but seems no show effect on my monitor

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, because what you are asking now is something different...